# How to check dependency list at runtime Gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I'm trying to find any duplicate libraries in my Android project developed with Intellij.

I've tried running `./gradlew dependencies` in the root directory of my project but I only got the following:

```
WARNING [Project: :app] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead
WARNING [Project: :facebookSDK] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead
WARNING [Project: :myLibrary] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead
WARNING [Project: :sherlockNavigationDrawer] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead
WARNING [Project: :viewPagerLibrary] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead
WARNING [Project: :myapp] WARNING: runProguard is deprecated (and will soon stop working); change to "minifyEnabled" instead
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Gradle version is 2.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root project doesn't have any dependencies. You need to execute the `dependencies` task on one of your subprojects.

```
$ ./gradlew :app:dependencies
```